# 'iwlist' -> interface doesn't support scanning (Ubuntu LTS 10.04)

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, networking, wifi, networkcard

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 (LTS) on a Samsung N150+ netbook. I cannot scan wifi  networks using `iwlist` and I would like to do so. Here is the output from some tests:

```
alex@alex-laptop:~/Desktop/GoogleCode$ iwlist eth1 scan
eth1      Interface doesn't support scanning.


alex@alex-laptop:~/Desktop/GoogleCode$ iwlist scan
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth1      Interface doesn't support scanning.

pan0      Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

So I try `iwconfig`

```
alex@alex-laptop:~/Desktop/GoogleCode$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

eth1      IEEE 802.11  Access Point: Not-Associated   
      Link Quality:5  Signal level:207  Noise level:168
      Rx invalid nwid:0  invalid crypt:0  invalid misc:0

pan0      no wireless extensions.
```

I have a `05:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation Device 4727 (rev 01)` from using `lspci`.

Any hints?

Comment: Did you try scanning as root?

Comment: @jordanm, this is a bit embarrassing but you are right that `root` was a necessary condition which I did not try. Could you put this as an answer?

Comment: glad it helped. answer added.

Answer (score 18):

You have to bring eth1 up before scanning.

`ifconfig eth1 up`

`iwlist eth1 s`

Comment: Being root or this didn't help me neither. But NetworkManager doesn't have any issue to scan the networks. Any idea ?

Answer (score 6):

If you have checked that you are root and your device is up:

```
sudo ifconfig eth1 up && sudo iwlist eth1 scan
```

And it still doesn't work, I found that:

```
iw dev wlan0 scan ap-force
```

Would work in my case. It seems that `iwlist` tool is obsolete and not anymore supported for recent wifi chipset.

Comment: Using the same tool: `iw wlan0 scan`

Answer (score 5):

The ability to scan using iwlist and associate to access points via iwconfig require root. In Ubuntu you can use the following:

```
sudo iwlist eth1 scan
```

Comment: Thanks. For me that does not resolve the issue. Would you have any other suggestion?

Comment: for people as confused as i am, this may happen: on my arch system, `sudo iw eth1 scan` fails but `sudo iwlist eth1 scan` succeeds

Answer (score 5):

Check `rfkill list all`

Mine had the following output

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
```

Which was causing the error Interface doesn't support scanning

To remove the block simply run the following command

```
sudo rfkill unblock wifi
```

Answer (score 4):

This issue can be also be caused by the wireless interface (I'll use wlan0 - not eth1) being in the wrong mode. To fix this you can use:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode Managed
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
```

You have to bring down the interface before changing the mode to prevent the interface being classified as busy.

Answer (score 4):

On Debian testing/bookworm ifconfig is not present.

First, find your interface name with one of these lines:

```
ip link show 
ls /sys/class/net
cat /proc/net/dev
netstat -i
```

To bring the interface up you have to type as root (my interface name is wlp1s0b1, yours is maybe wlan0):

```
ip link set wlp1s0b1 up
```

and now you can scan:

```
/sbin/iwlist wlp1s0b1 scan | grep -i ssid
```

Comment: I'm getting `cannot find device "wlp1s0b1"` on LM Una (20.3).

Comment: @Erwann find your interface name with: ip link show

Answer (score 2):

have you checked the interface name with command

```
ifconfig
```

and you can do ifconfig "interface-name" up
by example: for my wireless interface

```
ifconfig wlp2s0 up
```

the next thing to do is:

```
iwlist wlp2s0 scan
```