# Ubuntu 20.04 iwlist scanning : [interface] Interface doesn't support scanning : Operation not supported

Tags: ubuntu, networking, command-line, wifi, network-interface

I'm using ubuntu 20.04 (LTS).
I can't scan networks with iwlist.

```
$ sudo airmon-ng
PHY    Interface    Driver      Chipset

phy0    wlp1s0      ath10k_pci  Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)


$ sudo ifconfig wlp1s0up
$ sudo airmon-ng start wlp1s0

Found 4 processes that could cause trouble.
Kill them using 'airmon-ng check kill' before putting
the card in monitor mode, they will interfere by changing channels
and sometimes putting the interface back in managed mode

    PID Name
    601 avahi-daemon
    606 NetworkManager
    647 wpa_supplicant
    651 avahi-daemon

PHY Interface   Driver      Chipset

phy0    wlp1s0      ath10k_pci  Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)

        (mac80211 monitor mode vif enabled for [phy0]wlp1s0 on [phy0]wlp1s0mon)
        (mac80211 station mode vif disabled for [phy0]wlp1s0)

$ sudo iwlist wlp1s0mon scanning
wlp1s0mon  Interface doesn't support scanning : Operation not supported
```

This is different than [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45338/iwlist-interface-doesnt-support-scanning-ubuntu-lts-10-04) question.
I already tried all the suggested answers.

```
$ sudo iw dev wlp1s0mon scan ap-force
command failed: Operation not supported (-95)

$ rfkill list all
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Stop the monitor mode and try iwlist again, I thought iwlist has been deprecated. You are in monitor mode, is your device support monitor and scan at the same time, is ath10k_pci support that. What information are you hopping to get with : sudo iw dev wlp1s0mon scan ap-force, do you want to sniff or just check the parameters of your near wifi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This WLAN adapter (Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377) does not support promiscuous mode (aka monitor mode). You have two choices:

1. You can easily get yourself one of the Alfa cards for less than USD $70.
2. You can downgrade your Atheros firmware, but not guaranteed.

Reference: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/wifi-networks-not-scanning-in-monitor-mode-qualcomm-atheros-qca9377-802-11ac-wireless-network-adapter-4175666173/

Comment: The second choice nullify your answer. Is it the driver or the QCA9377 itself that doesn't support promiscuous mode (is not like monitor mode).